# Why does the position not change for the sprite nodes?

Tags: sprite-kit

I've commented the code. This is my first game so my knowledge is very shallow. I don't even know if there is a better way of doing this.

Now, the problem I am running into is that although the animation works, the position property I am printing is always 0. Why? My idea was that in the update method, I will check the position property and if it is above a certain height on the screen, I'll move the top sprite to the bottom (like a queue data structure - pull out from one end and add to the other end) and adjust the middle to be the top and the bottom to be the middle. That way, I just need 3 sprites to animate a scroll wheel of numbers.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Idea is to have a scrolling wheel of numbers animate. 
        The approach is to have 3 'number' sprite nodes inside a crop node. Only one sprite number node is visible at a given time
        because of the crop node's mask.
        Initially, number 0, 1 and 2 one under the other and a crop sprite to crop out everything but just one number
        that needs to be displayed. Then, we animate number 1 in and push out number 0 and then animate number 2 in and push
        out number 1. When the position of the sprite containing 0 moves above a certain position 'y', we move it to the bottom
        and have number 4 replace 0 so it can roll in next. So we have a continuous scrolling wheel of numbers */

        //A slot to hold the numbers
        let numSlot = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 180))

        //Create a crop node
        let cn = SKCropNode.init()

        //Add the crop node mask so only 1 number is visible
        cn.maskNode = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 180))

        //Add the number slot sprite to the crop node sprite at a certain position
        numSlot.addChild(cn)
        numSlot.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2 - 25)
        self.addChild(numSlot)

        //The three images that should live inside the numSlot node (with only 1 visible at a given time)
        let zeroSprite = SKSpriteNode.init(imageNamed: "0.png", normalMapped: false)
        let oneSprite = SKSpriteNode.init(imageNamed: "1.png", normalMapped: false)
        let twoSprite = SKSpriteNode.init(imageNamed: "2.png", normalMapped: false)

        //Add the three numbers to the numberHolderSprite and then add the numberHolderSprite to the crop Nod
        let numberHolderSprite = SKSpriteNode.init()
        numberHolderSprite.addChild(zeroSprite)
        oneSprite.position = CGPointMake(0, -120)
        numberHolderSprite.addChild(oneSprite)
        twoSprite.position = CGPointMake(0, -240)
        numberHolderSprite.addChild(twoSprite)


        //Add the number holder sprite to the crop node
        cn.addChild(numberHolderSprite)

        top = zeroSprite
        middle = oneSprite
        bottom = twoSprite

        var numSlotSpriteAction1 = SKAction.moveToY(top!.position.y + 500, duration: 0.5)
        var numSlotSpriteAction2 = SKAction.moveToY(middle!.position.y + 500, duration: 0.5)
        var numSlotSpriteAction3 = SKAction.moveToY(bottom!.position.y + 500, duration: 0.5)

        println("Position \(top!.position.y)")

        var numSlotGroupAction = SKAction.group([numSlotSpriteAction1, numSlotSpriteAction2, numSlotSpriteAction3])
        numberHolderSprite.runAction(numSlotGroupAction)

         println("Position \(top!.position.y)")

        //Just a simple background image
        let bg = SKSpriteNode.init(imageNamed: "bg.png", normalMapped: false)
        bg.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2)
        self.addChild(bg)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
println("Position \(top!.position.y)")
```

is being executed prior to any SKActions being run. top is really zeroSprite, and has the default position of 0, 0.

However, even if your SKActions were run, it would not affect top. This is because the SKActions are run on the numberHolderSprite node. This means numberHolderSprite's position will change, not the sub-nodes. That action will also not be run until the next animation loop is processed.

So I am guessing this code will not do what you expect it to do.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. I also have a println after the SKActions (infact in the update method also). Nothing is showing that the position of the numbers changing. So a simple question. I am asking SpriteKit to move the numbers inside numberHolderSprite - not numberHolderSprite itself. So why is it that you are saying numberHolderSprite's position will change and not its children's position.